# Cannot find module 'babel-preset-env' from PATH Did you mean "@babel/env"?

Tags: node.js, jestjs, babeljs

Jest cli suddently has stopped working, all test fails with:

```
Cannot find module 'babel-preset-env' from '/PATH'
    - Did you mean "@babel/env"?
```

I'm sure it is some kind of incompatibility between a module which uses babel 6 and my project with babel 7, but I'm not sure how can I solve.

This is package.json

```
{
  "name": "testing101",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel index.html",
    "test": "jest src/*.js --watchAll",
    "nyc": "nyc ava",
    "build": "babel src/*.js -d dist"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.5",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.13",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "nyc": "^14.1.1",
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.7.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "testURL": "http://localhost:1234/",
    "collectCoverage": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "nock": "^10.0.6"
  }
}
```

This is .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": ["env"]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In the test section of the .babelrc file you have accidentally used an unscoped preset (`"presets": ["env"]`). This used to be the way to do it before Babel 7 and the `@babel` scope. More than that, since you are already configuring `@babel/preset-env` as a global preset, you don't need to define it again for the test environment. Removing the entire test environment configuration as bellow should fix your problem:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

Answer (score 26):

you can try this via npm

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-env
```

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me:

`.babelrc`

```json
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

`.eslintrc` (add `@babel/core` to the existing list of configs)

```json
{
  "extends": ["@babel/core", ...EXISTING-CONFIGS-HERE]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I met this problem when I opened 2 terminal with 2 different versions of node. ( I installed NVM to use different versions of nodes )

- terminal 1:  npm install  ( correct, this is node 14 )
- terminal 2:  npm run dev  ( error, this is node 16 )

so the solution is quite simple:

1. remove the `node_modules`
2. run `npm install` and `npm run dev` with the same node version.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue with ReactJS project built using Sanity.
I added the below code to `.eslintrc`

```
{
  "extends": ["@sanity/eslint-config-studio", "@babel/core"]
}
```

Comment: Excellent fix, I was having the same issue with Sanity! +1

Answer (score 0):

i had the same error.. The Eslint was going crazy, this worked for me :

{
"extends": ["@sanity/eslint-config-studio", "@babel/core"],
"parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
"parserOptions": {
"requireConfigFile": false,
"babelOptions": {
"presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
}
}